# Tensorflow Data Validation does not identify anomalies in numerical features

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow-data-validation

I've been testing Tensorflow Data Validation (version 0.22.0) to use in my current ML pipelines and I noticed it does not get any anomaly in numerical features. For instance,

```
> import pandas as pd  
> import pyarrow 
> import tensorflow as tf 
> import apache_beam as beam 
> import apache_beam.io.iobase 
> import tensorflow_data_validation as tfdv 
> print('TFDV version: {}'.format(tfdv.version.__version__))
> 
> train_df = pd.DataFrame({
>     'FeatA' : ['A'] * 1000,
>     'FeatB' : ['B'] * 1000,
>     'FeatC' : [10] * 1000,
>     'FeatD' : [50.2] * 1000 })
> 
> eval_df = pd.DataFrame({
>     'FeatA' : ['A1'] * 1000,
>     'FeatB' : ['B1'] * 1000,
>     'FeatC' : [4] * 1000,
>     'FeatD' : [200.43] * 1000 })
> 
> train_stats  = tfdv.generate_statistics_from_dataframe(train_df)
> schema = tfdv.infer_schema(statistics = train_stats) 
> eval_stats = tfdv.generate_statistics_from_dataframe(eval_df) 
> anomalies = tfdv.validate_statistics(statistics = eval_stats, schema = schema)
> tfdv.display_anomalies(anomalies)
```

The anomalies were detected only in *FeatA* and *FeatB* which are categorical ones. But in *FeatC* and *FeatD*, TFDV does not detect anything.

The result is shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ioysm.png)

I've tried also setting skew and drift comparators, but no changes. I guess it has to do with the auto-generated schema which has no domain mapped for the numerical features.

Anyone has any idea of how to get TFDV working for numerical features?

Comment: This is a good observation. Will investigate further and will let you know.

Comment: any news on this issue? Thank you!!

Comment: It's being tracked in the Github Issue, https://github.com/tensorflow/data-validation/issues/131.

Comment: relevant comment :- https://github.com/tensorflow/data-validation/issues/131#issuecomment-737795663

Answered by kennysong :- 
"You need to manually set an inline FloatDomain in the Feature. It's not generated automatically by infer_schema().

tfdv.get_feature(schema, 'FeatC').float_domain.name = 'FeatC'
tfdv.get_feature(schema, 'FeatC').float_domain.min = 0.0
tfdv.get_feature(schema, 'FeatC').float_domain.max = 100.0
After that, validate_statistics() should identify the out-of-bounds features."

Answer (score 0):

Normally, tfdv does not infer domains for numerical values, you have now 3 possible solutions:

1- Change the type of the dataframe column to str and thus it will be considered as a Bytes feature.

2- Add an int_domain (float_domain for FeatD) to your features and determine your desired min and max

3- Only for int features you can set int_domain.is_categorical to True, and then use a drift/skew comparator. You will be able to detect new values within the Top k value.

Comment: I added `feature.int_domain.is_categorical = True` to a categorical feature which is of type INT. Then used `feature.drift_comparator.infinity_norm.threshold = 0.01` to detect drift. It displayed no anomalies found. But when I converted the feature to string, it detected an anomaly with high Linfty distance. So, solution 3 did not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

We need use jensen_shannon_divergence skew comparator for Numerical Features and infinity_norm for Categorical Features

tfdv.get_feature(schema_updated,'SALES').skew_comparator.jensen_shannon_divergence.threshold = 0.001

skew_anomalies = tfdv.validate_statistics(statistics=new_dataset_stats, schema=schema, serving_statistics=old_dataset_stats)
display_anomalies(skew_anomalies)

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @durga, TFDV has added a new feature that allows us to detect skew for numeric features. Specify a jensen_shannon_divergence threshold instead of an infinity_norm threshold in the skew_comparator.

Example:

```
tfdv.get_feature(schema, 'total_actions').skew_comparator.jensen_shannon_divergence.threshold = 0.01
```

If you want to check for max and min value range, you need to manually set an inline `FloatDomain`/`IntDomain` in the Feature. It's not generated automatically by infer_schema():

Example:

```
tfdv.get_feature(schema, 'total_actions').int_domain.name = 'total_actions'
tfdv.get_feature(schema, 'total_actions').int_domain.min = 0
tfdv.get_feature(schema, 'total_actions').int_domain.max = 1400
```